# Standalone 328P Arduino

Tags: atmega328, bootloader

I am creating a standalone Arduino using Atmega328P. The circuit is below.

[image]

However, I'm seeing

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 error
```

whenever I try to burn the Arduino Uno bootloader. I'm assuming that the chip isn't responding to the SPI lines?

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't see it.

My connections are

```
SCLK --> Arduino Pin 13
MISO --> Arduino Pin 12
MOSI --> Arduino Pin 11
Reset --> Arduino Pin 10

VIN --> 5V
GND --> GND
```

I'm using a true Arduino UNO as the ISP. I've uploaded the ArduinoISP code into it, choose Arduino as ISP as Programmer and Arduino Uno on boards. The programming connections are just wired from Arduino UNO pins to some vias I've purposely added on the layout.

As mentioned in the comments, I'm adding an image of the layout here.

[image]

I've tried this very circuit on an atmega328P soldered in a TQFP adapter and with the other components soldered on the adapter as well (looks like a jungle of wires) and somehow I was able to burn the bootloader.

Hoping someone can point out what's wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to run the ATmega at 3.3 V on a 16 MHz crystal?

Comment: Yes. Will there be a problem on doing it @tttapa?

Comment: Check the datasheet, that voltage/frequency combination is out of spec. Either raise the voltage, or lower the frequency.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Yeah, just saw it now on the datasheet.

Comment: I've just tried removing the regulator and connecting 5V with the VCC line. I'm still seeing the same error. Would there be other mistakes?

Comment: It's not possible to see on that schematic how your programming device is connected up to the board. Also PCB layout images could be useful to check for mistakes.

Comment: Do you know if the clock is running? Or can you provide a clock? 10µF between dtr and reset? and no diode from reset to vcc?

Comment: C3 should be 0.1uF for Serial downloads.  D10 from the ISP connects to Reset directly, not thru the cap.

Comment: @Majenko I've added the layout on the question. The SPI lines from Arduino UNO are tapped on the SPI lines of the atmega328P. There are vias on the left side of the vias so I can add wires. The connections are stated in the question above.

Comment: @Jot yes, I've looked at it on scope and the clock is running. I mean  i have 16 MHz oscillator on it. I'm not using FTDI when burning the bootloader. I'm using the SPI lines. So basically, the cap there is left floating.

Comment: Is there a ground pour or ground plane layer that has been omitted from that image?

Comment: It's not obvious from the schematic, but pins 3,4,21 need to be grounded.  Did you do that?

Comment: @Majenko yes, there is ground pour that is not shown. But yes, all ground pins are connected to ground.

Comment: noobiejp, I think we mentioned a lot of things and you answered our questions. So we have to look for more obscure things. Perhaps you can try the Nick Gammon sketch https://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader Perhaps you can try a programmer instead of Arduino as ISP. Perhaps your atmega32u4 is broken. Do you have another Arduino Uno that you can try to put a bootloader into? If that works, you can try to put a bootloader into a Leonardo or Micro. If that works, you can try your pcb board.

Comment: Your power supply is incorrect. You cannot connect a 317 this way

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using a lm317 voltage regulator to power your atmega328p MCU but I think you forgot the part that lm317 needs feedback of 1.25v with voltage divider network to set its variable output voltage in the schematic you have connected adj pin of  lm317 directly to GND.
S0 check your output vtg from your regulator and another issue voltage regulator only works great when difference between regulating voltage is lower then the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

From the schematic it appears you are using a LM317 voltage regulator from USB V_IN.  The voltage drop is too large and your issues may be due to brown out, i.e. insufficient voltage:  See [this SE post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214371/lm317-dropout-voltage).  You can solve it by using a lower dropout regulator (5 V to 3.3 V) or just use the standard USB 5 V, bypass V_IN to V_CC.

Comment: Hi! I've already tried bypassing the regulator by removing it and tying VIN to VCC. So the whole VCC line will get 5V straight from USB. However, still not burning the bootloader.